# Как при клике по элементу из списка свернуть все списки кроме текущего?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написал вот такой код

```js
$(document).on('click', 'body', function(el) {
  if (!$(el.target).parents('.dropdown').hasClass('open')) {
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('open').children('ul.dropdown-list').slideUp();
  }
})
$(document).on('click', 'button.userdata', function() {
  if ($(this).parent('.dropdown').hasClass('open')) {
    $(this).parent('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
    $(this).siblings('ul.dropdown-list').slideUp(200);
  } else {
    $(this).parent('.dropdown').addClass('open');
    $(this).siblings('ul.dropdown-list').slideDown(200);
  }
})
$(document).on('click', 'ul.dropdown-list>li', function() {
  $(this).parents('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
  $(this).parent('ul.dropdown-list').slideUp(200);
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).parent().siblings('button').children('span').text(text).attr('title', text);
  $(this).parents('.dropdown').siblings('.list').val(id);
})
```

```css
ul.dropdown-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button name="post" class="userdata">
        <span title="Отдел мониторинга">Отдел мониторинга</span>
                </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-list">
    <li data-id="1">Отдел IT</li>
    <li data-id="2">Отдел мониторинга</li>
    <li data-id="3">Отдел продаж</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button name="post" class="userdata">
        <span>Должность</span>
                </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-list">
    <li data-id="1" data-dep="1">Руководитель отдела IT</li>
    <li data-id="2" data-dep="1">Web-разработчик</li>
    <li data-id="3" data-dep="1">Web-дизайнер</li>
    <li data-id="4" data-dep="2">Руководитель отдела мониторинга</li>
    <li data-id="5" data-dep="3">Руководитель отдела продаж</li>
    <li data-id="6" data-dep="2">Менеджер отдела мониторинга</li>
    <li data-id="7" data-dep="3">Менеджер отдела продаж</li>
    <li data-id="8" data-dep="3">Офис-менеджер</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

почти все как надо но только если я кликаю по соседнему выпадающему списку то текущий тоже должен свернуться, а этого не происходит, так как условие верное.

Не понимаю как написать логику..

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вёртску, будет проще помочь. Решение в целом вполне простое.

Comment: @Klimenkomud исправил

Comment: При клике на кнопку с классом `userdata` - свернуть все дропдауны, кроме текущего, правильно?

Comment: @Klimenkomud да

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После клика на кнопку находим все `dropdown` кроме родительского и убираем класс `open`, в этих же блоках находим списки и скрываем.

```
let pd = $(this).parents('.dropdown');

$('.dropdown').not(pd)
              .removeClass('open')
              .find('ul.dropdown-list')
              .slideUp(200);
```

```js
$(document).on('click', 'body', function(el) {
  if (!$(el.target).parents('.dropdown').hasClass('open')) {
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('open').children('ul.dropdown-list').slideUp();
  }
})
$(document).on('click', 'button.userdata', function() {

  let pd = $(this).parents('.dropdown');
  
  $('.dropdown').not(pd)
                .removeClass('open')
                .find('ul.dropdown-list')
                .slideUp(200);
  
  if ($(this).parent('.dropdown').hasClass('open')) {
    $(this).parent('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
    $(this).siblings('ul.dropdown-list').slideUp(200);
  } else {
    $(this).parent('.dropdown').addClass('open');
    $(this).siblings('ul.dropdown-list').slideDown(200);
  }
})
$(document).on('click', 'ul.dropdown-list>li', function() {
  $(this).parents('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
  $(this).parent('ul.dropdown-list').slideUp(200);
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).parent().siblings('button').children('span').text(text).attr('title', text);
  $(this).parents('.dropdown').siblings('.list').val(id);
})
```

```css
ul.dropdown-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button name="post" class="userdata">
        <span title="Отдел мониторинга">Отдел мониторинга</span>
                </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-list">
    <li data-id="1">Отдел IT</li>
    <li data-id="2">Отдел мониторинга</li>
    <li data-id="3">Отдел продаж</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button name="post" class="userdata">
        <span>Должность</span>
                </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-list">
    <li data-id="1" data-dep="1">Руководитель отдела IT</li>
    <li data-id="2" data-dep="1">Web-разработчик</li>
    <li data-id="3" data-dep="1">Web-дизайнер</li>
    <li data-id="4" data-dep="2">Руководитель отдела мониторинга</li>
    <li data-id="5" data-dep="3">Руководитель отдела продаж</li>
    <li data-id="6" data-dep="2">Менеджер отдела мониторинга</li>
    <li data-id="7" data-dep="3">Менеджер отдела продаж</li>
    <li data-id="8" data-dep="3">Офис-менеджер</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.userdata').click(function(event) {
  $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
  $(this).parent('.dropdown').addClass('open')
})
```

Comment: это не решение, а где функция slideUp slideDown?